# React Component ESLint says Prefer Default Export

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I keep getting this error from ESLint on my component.

**ESLint: says Prefer Default Export (import/prefer-default-export)**

Here's is how the component looks

```
export class mycomponent extends React.Component {

  render() {

    //stuff here

  }
}
```

What is it asking for? How can I fix this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

Comment: First result on google for "eslint prefer-default-export": https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/prefer-default-export.md

Comment: I've seen that but it's different to my component so I don't understand what I need to change on my component. Also, I got the component format code from React website itself :o/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to specify your export as default like this:

```
export default class mycomponent extends React.Component {

  render() {

    //stuff here

  }
}
```

(notice the added word `default`) and then in other files you may import your component with:

`import mycomponent from './mycomponent.js';`

assuming that the component is being included from within the same directory and is defined in the file mycomponent.js.

You can also avoid having a default export if your file contains multiple exported things with names such as:

```
export const foo = 'foo';
export const bar = 'bar';
```

or you could even leave your original file exactly as it is without the word `default` and import it using a batch import:

`import * as mycomponent from './mycomponent.js';`